# Checkboxes icons are not shown properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, checkbox

i am making an app in which i am using tableview cell and in uitableview cell i am using button in the form of checkbox. i have two images named "uncheck.png" and "tick.png" when i click on that button tick is shown but uncheck image is disappear i want that tick image on that uncheck image...![image: i want that tick image slightly that square image]

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"cell";
    tablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.activitiesTableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[tablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    }

    UILabel *valuedate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:11];
    UILabel *msg = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:12];
    UILabel *date = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:13];
    UILabel *time = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:14];
    [valuedate setText:@"Demo"];
    [msg  setText:@"How are You?"];
    date.text=@"14/07/2014";
    time.text=@"A 08:16";


    // [cell.textLabel setText:activityModel.userName];
    valuedate.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI" size:15];
    msg.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:10.0];
    date.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:9];
    time.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:9];



    if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
    {
         [cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        //[cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else
    {
         [cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

    cell.button.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your uncheck image as background image using

```
[cell.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and then your check image as image

```
[cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Now you can change the image of button at each tap but the background image will be fixed. when the button is selected set the tick image as image else set it as nil

Replace your code with this

```
[cell.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.button setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
    {
         [cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

May be this can solve your problem [image]

Comment: not working fine... first cell is not showing background image then next cell showing background image then next cell is not unchecked..

Comment: May be this happening because of your cell reusability so try the edited code given in my answer.

Comment: fine but 1 more issue i want that tick image slightly outside from that uncheck image how it can be done.. see my updated screen shot...

Comment: @MishalAwan make you uncheck image with some padding outside its boxes so that it will just cover the whole button but leave some space and increase the size of your tick image and it should work

Comment: I mean to say just create an uncheck image using photoshop or anything having some padding outside the image box. because your setbackgroundimage simply fill the whole button back view with given image. for example find the image in my answer